# How to Send Conference Notes to Managers

Tags: travel, conferences

- It's my first month at a new job, and my managers sent me to an (expensive) conference overseas to learn about a new market segment
- I want to impress them by sending a summary email with notes from all the workshops/talks
- What format for the email would you suggest? Daily? Detailed from each talk I participate or should I send only a bullet-list summary at the end of the event?

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a wiki at your company,I'd suggest doing your overall detailed writeup there, and then emailing people with a high-level, bullet-point summary, and a link to the wiki should they wish to learn more.

Answer (score 3):

If the conference you were sent to provided you with information that could be useful to some of your other colleagues, my suggestion would be to create a document that summaries all of the information you receive over the course of the conference. You could then upload this document to a central repository that is accessible to all of your colleagues. Following this you can send your boss an email with a link to the location and ask him if they think it could be useful to distribute this link company-wide, or if there's any changes to be made before doing-so.

The benefit of this is that to be able to reply to you, your boss will have to at a minimum scan what you have prepared. Even if they don't look thoroughly, they will be able to see how much information you have gotten and therefore how valuable it was to send you. Furthermore, you are sending only one email (therefore not spamming your boss' inbox) and moves the focus away from you "trying to impress your boss" to "trying to do as good a job as possible".